# Rails - layout won't apply to desired action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply a specific layout to one action in a controller in my Rails (v. 4.2.5) app, but it will not work.  Oddly (or maybe not so oddly), the layout will be used used to render an action if that action is part of the 'resources' route, but not to the action that I need this to work for, which is not part of 'resources'.  Sorry if that seems confusing, here's the relevant code and explanation...

**routes.rb** - here I have the standard resources routes for my `entries` controller, as well as a an additional route for 'inputs'

```
get '/entries/inputs' => 'entries#inputs.html'
resources :entries
```

**entries_controller.rb** - here I'm trying to apply the `layouts/cached.html.erb` to the 'inputs' action

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    layout "cached", only: [:inputs]

    def inputs
    end

    def index
        @entry = Entry.all
    end
end
```

As it is, `layouts/cached.html.erb` does not get applied to the 'inputs' action.  *However*, if I swap out the second line of code in the controller for this:

```
layout "cached", only: [:index]
```

the layout is successfully rendered for the 'index' action.

What am I missing here?  Why will this layout apply to one action but not the other?

Comment: If this is getting voted down, I'd appreciate knowing why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
layout :resolve_layout

def inputs
end

def index
    @entry = Entry.all
end

private

def resolve_layout
 case action_name
when "inputs"
  "cached"
else
  "application"
end
end
end
```

And in `Routes`:

```
get 'entries/inputs' => 'entries#inputs'
```

Comment: Hm... thank you, but this is still having the same issue.  It won't use the layout for `when "inputs"` but it will if I switch that to `when "index"`.

Comment: THANK you!  This was a very frustrating problem, you've really helped me clear a silly hurdle that was holding back an important step in the app development.